# Jade syntax highlighting not working in IntelliJ (Darcula L&F)

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, pug

Jade template file in JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA 12.0 using new Darcula theme. Has anyone experienced similar problems with IntelliJ/Pycharm/RubyMine/WebStorm and Jade plugin?

Does anyone have a temporary solution until JetBrains fixes this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've [submitted a request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2253) to address this issue.

At the moment you can change colors manually in `File` | `Settings` | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts`, **Jade** (create a copy of the default scheme so that you can make changes).